# How to know when the topology of the vector space comes from an inner product?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inner-products

There is a result which gives an if and only if criterion for knowing when the norm of a normed linear space comes from an inner product; it is so if and only if it satisfies the parallelogram law:
\begin{align*}
||x+y||^2 + ||x-y||^2 = 2 ||x||^2 + 2||y||^2
\end{align*}
However, this speaks about the norm function. Is there a criterion to address the underlying topology instead? More precisely, given a normed linear space $(V,||.||)$, how do we know that there does or doesn't exist an inner product $\left<.,.\right>$ such that the topology from $(V,\sqrt{\left<.,.\right>})$ matches the topology of the original space? For example, in the case of $(\mathbb{R}^n, ||.||_p)$ the answer to this question is positive for any $p$ since the norms are equivalent in a finite dimensional vector space. What about $(L^p [0,1],||.||_p)$ for instance for $1\leq p \leq \infty$?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are asking, but if you have a normed space, then its topology is generated by the norm. If that norm satisfies the parallelogram law, then you can reconstruct the corresponding inner product from it. That is, that inner product then induces the original norm.

Comment: Oh right, I got it now. Say, if you are given the p-norm with p = 3, then you are asking how to get to the inner product, since the parallelogram law does not hold for that norm. That's an interesting question!

Comment: Yes, asking if it even exists for such a space

Comment: The following link leads to a dissertation by H.B. Lambert: Topological characterization of an inner product space (1968). It seems to be in the direction you are looking for.  https://ttu-ir.tdl.org/server/api/core/bitstreams/80dd45a8-ab65-461c-9cd3-ed3f2c4d87c0/content

Comment: Thank you, I shall check this out. May I ask where you search for these resources?

Comment: I found it with Google by searching "topological characterization of inner product spaces".

Comment: A infinite dimensional Banach space is isomorphic to a Hilbert space if and only if every closed subspace is complemented. See [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplementarySubspaceProblem.html).